# Stripping away every line that doesn't start with a certain prefix

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that strips out all lines that don't start with a certain prefix. Using [this tip](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=188907) I came up with this:

```
(?:(?!\nLAST-MODIFIED:[^\n]+\n).*)
```

This doesn't seem to work properly. What am I doing wrong? And yes, I'm aware of the fact that this will always strip the first line, whether it is prefixed with `LAST-MODIFIED:` or not. But I'm positive that the first line will never be a `LAST-MODIFIED:` line, so it should be safe. My suggested fix would be `(?:(?!(\n|^)LAST-MODIFIED:[^\n]+\n).*)` if I wanted to be perfectly safe.

Comment: What language are you using? Regex behaves differently in different implementations.

Comment: I'm using Qt's regex features. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qregexp.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will this do what you need it to?

```
(^(?!LAST-MODIFIED)[^\n]*)+
```

Explanation:

- `^` - match the beginning of a line
- `(?!LAST-MODIFIED)` - check that it doesn't begin with last-modified
- `[^\n]*` - if the above is true, match everything until you find a line break
- `+` - repeat

Comment: I believe that ^ matches the beginning of the string in Qt. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qregexp.html

Comment: @Pieter - then replace it with the new line if that works better for you

Comment: Really appreciate the contextual explanation of what each pattern does. Super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:- Oops, you wanted lines that DIDN'T start with a certain prefix. See the edit below:

If this isn't detecting content over multiple lines, you can do this easily from a shell with grep:

```
grep -v -P "^LAST-MODIFIED:.*" oldfile > newfile
```

I suggest piping it into a new file and checking it, then moving the new file over the old file with `mv newfile oldfile` rather than changing the file directly, to avoid potentially losing data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are working with but in .NET/C# this works (tested):

```
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^(LAST-MODIFIED\:).*$");
    Debug.WriteLine(r.Replace("LAST-MODIFIED:2012-01-01", ""));
```

^ matches the start of the line and $ matches the end
The period/dot "." matches zero or more occurrences of any character except linebreak